# What is the replacement for ListSelect in Vaadin 22?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin14

I'm trying to update an application from Vaadin 7/8 to Vaadin 22.

`ListSelect` is gone, so I need a new widget field that satisfies these requirements:

1. Allows choosing multiple items
2. Suitable for use in `FormLayout` with value bound using `Binder`
3. Scrolls automatically when there are more than a handful of choices

None of the widgets in Vaadin 22 seem to qualify:

- `Select` and `ComboBox` only choose one item
- `ListBox` says *...designed to be used as a lightweight scrollable selection list rather than a form input field*
- `Grid` does not implement `HasValue` so can't be used with `Binder`
- `CheckBoxGroup` doesn't look like it will scroll (requirement #3) (I haven't actually tried yet though)

What am I missing here?? What is the new equivalent of the old `ListSelect`?

Answer (score 2):

If your `Grid` is set to multiselect mode, you can use `grid.asMultiSelect()` to return a `MultiSelect` object that does implement `HasValue` and can be used with `Binder`. Similarly, in single-select mode, `grid.asSingleSelect()` returns a bindable `SingleSelect` object.

Comment: Ah thanks. Not obvious but it looks like it will work.

Comment: OK, but just to be clear - you have to bind the `MultiSelect` to the `Binder` but add the `Grid` to the `FormLayout`, correct? Somewhat awkward.

Comment: That's right. MultiSelect is just a helper.

Comment: Sorry the Vaadin people disagree now. Current situation apparently is "there is no good answer". https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/2707

Comment: According to my understanding, there will be a better solution coming up in a V23 minor release (maybe 23.1 or 23.2), but at the moment, your best choice is either the Grid as MultiSelect or an add-on like MultiselectCombobox.